# C2DM message is not received

Tags: android, android-c2dm

why is C2DM push notification message sometimes cannot be received by
the device although the status is success?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server returns a 200 success message, then the expired key is cannot be the case.

The truth is C2DM is not reliable to always send your message (it may send it with delay, if you send multiple there is a change the order will be altered, or it might not get on the other side at all).

I had a somewhat similar problem, when in my first day of sending messages I was getting the 200 status code but no messages on the device. I got the same answer that the one I'm giving you know.

Also, always make sure when you want to receive your messages that you have an internet connection.

Comment: do you have find website explains it? It is very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I can provide you with some other StackOverflow similar threads:
[Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024493/reliability-of-c2dm), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256891/1300817)

Here is a quote from Google's C2DM page (you can find it under *Introduction*):
**C2DM makes no guarantees about delivery or the order of messages. So, for example, while you might use this feature to tell an instant messaging application that the user has new messages, you probably would not use it to pass the actual messages.**